# Python using lamda function error missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have the following program

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


class Grilla:
    colorCelda = "black"
colorDefault = "white"
colorBorde = "black"
bordeDefault = "black"

def __init__(self, root, master, x, y, size):
    """ Constructor of the object called by Cell(...) """
    self.master = master
    self.abs = x
    self.ord = y
    self.size = size
    self.fill = False

def switch(self):
    """ Switch if the cell is filled or not. """
    self.fill = not self.fill

def draw(self):
    # dibujar en el canvas
    if self.master is not None:
        outline = Grilla.colorBorde
        fill = Grilla.colorCelda

        if not self.fill:
            outline = Grilla.bordeDefault
            fill = Grilla.colorDefault

        xmin = self.abs * self.size
        xmax = xmin + self.size
        ymin = self.ord * self.size
        ymax = ymin + self.size

        self.master.create_rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, fill=fill, outline=outline)


class CellGrilla(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, numFil, numCol, tamGrid, *args, **kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, width=tamGrid * numCol, height=tamGrid * numFil, *args, **kwargs)
    self.button1 = tk.Button(self, command=lambda: self.button1_clicked)
    self.cellSize = tamGrid

    self._grid = []
    for row in range(numFil):

        line = []
        for column in range(numCol):
            line.append(Grilla(master, self, column, row, tamGrid))

        self._grid.append(line)

    # memorize the cells that have been modified to avoid many switching of state during mouse motion.
    self.switched = []

    # bind click action
    # self.bind("<Button-1>", self.button1_clicked)

    self.draw()

def draw(self):
    for row in self._grid:
        for cell in row:
            cell.draw()

def _coordenadas(self, event):
    row = int(event.y / self.cellSize)
    column = int(event.x / self.cellSize)
    return row, column

def button1_clicked(self, event):
    self.bind("<Button-1>", self.button1_clicked)
    row, column = self._coordenadas(event)
    cell = self._grid[row][column]
    cell.switch()
    cell.draw()
    pass

def button2_clicked(self):
    pass

def button3_clicked(self):
    pass

def button4_clicked(self):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
app = Tk()

# Tamaño de canvas x tamaño de pixeles
grid = CellGrilla(app, 75, 75, 10)

grid.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=4, sticky="news")

boton1 = Button(app, text="Dibujar", command=grid.button1_clicked, height=1, width=30)
boton2 = Button(app, text="DDA", command=grid.button2_clicked, height=1, width=30)
boton3 = Button(app, text="Zoom in", command=grid.button3_clicked, height=1, width=30)
boton4 = Button(app, text="Zoom out", command=grid.button3_clicked, height=1, width=30)
boton5 = Button(app, text="Bresenham", command=grid.button3_clicked, height=1, width=30)
boton6 = Button(app, text="Clear", command=grid.button4_clicked, height=1, width=30)

boton1.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="news")
boton2.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="news")
boton3.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="news")
boton4.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="news")
boton5.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky="news")
boton6.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky="news")

app.mainloop()
```

Right now I'm trying to figure out how to make the first button work, when nothing is pressed and I press the grid, nothing happens. When I press the button "Dibujar" it should be able to draw on the grid, however I've tried to implement de "if else" function but I can't figure out how to do it correctly. I've been trying to figure it out with "lambda" but I get the following error when pressing the first button

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "E:\Python\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1884, in **call**
>
> return self.func(*args)
>
> TypeError: button1_clicked() missing 1 required positional argument:
> 'event'

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and it's my first time programming in python so I'd really appreciate if someone could help me figure it out.

Comment: This is a tricky question. In your definition of `button1_clicked(self, event)` you specified that it takes an event as an argument. The problem is that buttons don't create events like that.

Comment: The callback to a button does not get passed any arguments when it is called. The kind of callback that gets an event is when you bind it to a widget with a call to `bind` similar to the one you have in the callback itself. Usually, people don't call `bind` in the callback, but in the initialization of the widgets. You would only put a `bind` call in a callback if you were trying to change the behavior of the widgets when the callback was triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


class Grilla:
    colorCelda = "black"
    colorDefault = "white"
    colorBorde = "black"
    bordeDefault = "black"

    def __init__(self, root, master, x, y, size):
        """ Constructor of the object called by Cell(...) """
        self.master = master
        self.abs = x
        self.ord = y
        self.size = size
        self.fill = False

    def switch(self):
        """ Switch if the cell is filled or not. """
        self.fill = not self.fill

    def reset(self):
        """ Clears the cell """
        self.fill = False

    def draw(self):
        # dibujar en el canvas
        if self.master is not None:
            outline = Grilla.colorBorde
            fill = Grilla.colorCelda

            if not self.fill:
                outline = Grilla.bordeDefault
                fill = Grilla.colorDefault

            xmin = self.abs * self.size
            xmax = xmin + self.size
            ymin = self.ord * self.size
            ymax = ymin + self.size

            self.master.create_rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, fill=fill, outline=outline)


class CellGrilla(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, numFil, numCol, tamGrid, *args, **kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, width=tamGrid * numCol, height=tamGrid * numFil, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.square_clicked)
        self.cellSize = tamGrid

        self.pen_type = "draw"

        self._grid = []
        for row in range(numFil):

            line = []
            for column in range(numCol):
                line.append(Grilla(master, self, column, row, tamGrid))

            self._grid.append(line)

        # memorize the cells that have been modified to avoid many switching of state during mouse motion.
        self.switched = []

        self.draw()

    def square_clicked(self, event):
        row, column = self._coordenadas(event)
        cell = self._grid[row][column]
        if self.pen_type == "draw":
            cell.switch()
        elif self.pen_type == "rubber":
            cell.reset()
        cell.draw()

    def draw(self):
        for row in self._grid:
            for cell in row:
                cell.draw()

    def _coordenadas(self, event):
        # `int(a / b)` is the same as `a // b`
        row = event.y // self.cellSize
        column = event.x // self.cellSize
        return row, column

    def switch_to_draw(self):
        self.pen_type = "draw"

    def switch_to_rubber(self):
        self.pen_type = "rubber"

    def clear(self):
        for row in self._grid:
            for cell in row:
                cell.reset()
                cell.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Tk()

    # Tamaño de canvas x tamaño de pixeles
    grid = CellGrilla(app, 75, 75, 10)

    grid.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=4, sticky="news")

    draw_btn = Button(app, text="Draw", command=grid.switch_to_draw, height=1, width=30)
    rubber_btn = Button(app, text="Rubber/Eraser", command=grid.switch_to_rubber, height=1, width=30)
    reset_btn = Button(app, text="Clear everything", command=grid.clear, height=1, width=30)

    draw_btn.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="news")
    rubber_btn.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="news")
    reset_btn.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="news")

    app.mainloop()
```

I added a variable that stores what the user is doing `pen_type`. Later you can add colour by changing the value of `pen_type`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your definition of `button1_clicked`, it has mandatory `event` parameter. But nothing is passed during a method call. Either you remove it, or make it optional through assignment a default value.

```
def button1_clicked(self, event=None):
    ...
```

**UPD**: As `TheLizzard` mentioned, `event` param is used inside of the method. So, it should be always passed.

Comment: `event` is used inside the method so you can't make it optional.